# Post Selected Model from WebGrid using Jquery in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, controller, viewmodel, jquery-post

In MVC, I have a WebGrid. This WebGrid is populated using ViewModel called PaginatedList. Which indeed have the actual ViewModel collection i.e RequestViewModel collection.

On a particular event, I would like to send the selected ViewModel(i.e RequestViewModel) to Controller using Jquery Post. I don't prefer to use $("form").Serialize() to send whole collection.

Please help. Thanks for your time.

Edit:
**In Controller:**

```
var accessRequestViewModel=objAccessRequest.FetchAll();
var paginatedUAReqs=new PaginatedList<AccessRequestsViewModel>(accessRequestViewModel);
return view(paginatedUAReqs);
```

**In View:**

```
@model PaginatedList<RequestsViewModel>
var accessReqWebGrid= new WebGrid(model);
WebGrid.Column("ID");
WebGrid.Column("Name");
WebGrid.Column("Action");// This column has a drop down. On change of selection, jquery post has to be done. Sending the selected row as a model to controller.
```

**In Javascript(Jquery)**

```
$('select[name="Action"]').change(function () {
// Here I would like to send the viewmodel i.e AccessRequestViewModel object along with following Id and TextArea values
$.post(url, {USER_REQ_ID: $("#NotesRowId").val(), Notes: $("#commentsTxtArea").val(), Action: actionVal }, function (data) {
});
```

**Things Tried:**

*In Javascript:*

```
var AccessReqViewModel = {
                                REQ_ID: "10",
                                REQ_USER_NAME:"uausername"
                            }
$.post(url, {AR_ViewModel:AccessReqViewModel  USER_REQ_ID: $("#NotesRowId").val(), Notes: $("#commentsTxtArea").val(), Action: actionVal }, function (data) {
    });
```

*In Controller:*

```
 public ActionResult SaveActionNotes(AccessRequestsViewModel AR_ViewModel, int USER_REQ_ID, string Notes,string Action){}
```

Breakpoint is being hit but the values in viewmodel are not the one which i have sent.

Comment: You're going to have to supply some code examples, and please indicate what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

Used the following

```
$.ajax({
                                url: commentsWinPath,
                                type: 'POST',
                                dataType: 'json',
                                contentType: 'application/json',
                                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                                success: function (data) {
                                    //...
                                },
                                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                    //...
                                }
                            });
```

$.post didn't worked for me and content type played major role in solving the issue.